# for each loop in hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

i'm new in ruby i'm learning hashes and my below code is behaving like hell please help

```
hash = {"15" => {:a=>"a_15", :b=>"b_15", :c=>"c_15 ", :d=>"Pass"},
        "16" => {:a=>"d_16", :b=>"e_16", :c=>"f_16 ", :d=>"Fail"}}



mod= {}
h = {}
hash.each do |k,v|
  v.each do |x,y|
    mod[x] = y
  end
  h[k] = mod
  # mod={}    # i don't want to use this technique 
              # as its always creates a new object which is not required
end

p h
```

expected output:

```
{"15" => {:a=>"a_15", :b=>"b_15", :c=>"c_15 ", :d=>"Pass"},
 "16" => {:a=>"d_16", :b=>"e_16", :c=>"f_16 ", :d=>"Fail"}}
```

actual output :

```
{"15"=> {:a=>"d_16", :b=>"e_16", :c=>"f_16 ", :d=>"Fail"},
 "16"=> {:a=>"d_16", :b=>"e_16", :c=>"f_16 ", :d=>"Fail"}}
```

please help !!!! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After first iteration you got:

```
h == {"15" => {:a=>"a_15", :b=>"b_15", :c=>"c_15 ", :d=>"Pass"}}
```

where the value *is a reference to `mod`*. During second iteration you *change* `mod`, that apparently changes the value of `h['15']`, that *is referencing* `mod`.

To quick fix that:

```
h[k] = mod.dup
```

The above will produce cloned version of `mod`. To check the described behaviour, you might run your original code and then do:

```
h.values.each { |v| puts v.__id__ }
```

The above will print [the identifiers of the objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__) and you’ll see that all keys of resulting array are referencing the same object.

Comment: dup typically uses the class of the descendant object to create the new instance according to (http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/dup.)

is it necessary to create a new instance just for assignment ...for suppose if we have billions of records then dup will create billions of instance just for assignments..

Comment: I am not sure I understood a question. Since you want to have different hashes as values, you _are to create them_. Your initial approach with `mod = {}` might suit your needs better. I just pointed out to what the problem underlies the behaviour.

Comment: is there a better approach fo it.??? i mean can we use  the same object..throught

Comment: In your resulting hash you have two different objects: `{:a=>"a_15", :b=>"b_15", :c=>"c_15 ", :d=>"Pass"}` and `{:a=>"d_16", :b=>"e_16", :c=>"f_16 ", :d=>"Fail"}`. How do you suppose to use the single object for them? That contradicts the law of conservation of mass.